# Error installing SHA

Tags: installation, gcc, perl, cpan

I'm trying to install SHA using the following command

```
perl -MCPAN -e 'install Digest::SHA'
```

I also tried using:

```
sudo cpan

'install Digest::SHA'
```

But i'm getting a linker error:

```
/usr/local/bin/ld: this linker was not configured to use sysroots 
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status 
make: *** [blib/arch/auto/Digest/SHA/SHA.so] Error 1 
MSHELOR/Digest-SHA-5.84.tar.gz 
/usr/bin/make -- NOT OK 
Running make test 
Can't test without successful make 
Running make install 
Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible
```

Could someone please help me fix the error. My ubuntu version is 12.04

Comment: Please give your Ubuntu version.

Comment: @Manuel : 12.04

Comment: Can you ensure that make is installed on your system? Just run "/usr/bin/make" and add the results to your question, thanks!

Comment: @JorgeCastro: i used commands "sudo chmod +x make" followed by "./make".
it gives "make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop."
Is this what you meant?

Comment: @JorgeCastro: i checked my synaptic package manager. It shows that make is installed. version is 3.81-8.2ubuntu2

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the problem by reinstalling binutils.